# Android: Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme with action icons

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an activity in my manifest with this theme for backward compatibility:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

But as I run my application, the `Icon`s in the `ActionBar` are displayed as text instead of icon items. In my layout file they are declared as Icon items as you can observe here:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.company.myapp">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_sort"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

In the code above you can see that i'm setting the icon item to display always as action, so it should display the icon.

**Why is it ignoring what is in my layout file and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: I already tried that. Android Studio complains:
"Cannot resolve android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: You have  to add Support Library  v7 appcompat using the SDK Manager. See <http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html>

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`